# C# - private static method in partial class not shared between files?

Tags: c#, class, partial-classes

I'm creating `static partial class` like this.

If I put them in the **same file** there is **no** problem, but when I move one class to another file in the **same project**, this method `private_method_from_a()` does not exist anymore.

Is this by design? Do I miss something here?

```
    //File A
    public static partial class PartialClass
    {
        private static void private_method_from_a()
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }

    //File B
    public static partial class PartialClass
    {
        public static void public_method_b()
        {
            private_method_from_a();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using different `namespace`s?  Maybe show us the top of the files?

Comment: Yes, I didn't know it has the be in the same namespace. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the two files are in different `namespace`s, as @MickyD suggested in a comment. The reason for this problem is you're then making 2 *different* classes entirely. Chances are, one of them is in the namespace of your project, while the other is in the global namespace - that is, you didn't specify a namespace for it at all. Here's how the compiler sees them (suppose your project is called "MyProject", and has that name as the top-level namespace):

`partial class global::MyProject.PartialClass`

and

`partial class global::PartialClass`

Well, that's two distinct types, with *different fully qualified names*, both partial.

Make sure they're are both in the same namespace for the C# compiler to treat them as the same type.